# How can search in comma separated value list with ignore case sensitive like SELECT 'John' IN ('john','Peter');

Tags: mysql

How can search in comma separated value list  with ignore case sensitive like:

```
SELECT  'John'  IN  ('john','Peter');-- it return 0
```

if

```
SELECT  'john'  IN  ('john','Peter'); --it return 1
```

I want to ignore case sensitive to make search more optimal...

Comment: Can you please post the *valid* SQL code with case-insensitve search you want to enhance?

Comment: Note that most implementations of MySQL ARE case-insensitive - SELECT 'john' = 'John'; -> 1

Comment: I get `1` for both of these. [Case Sensitivity in String Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: what data types are the fields you are using?

Comment: "but if it come from data field in a table like ('jhon','peter'); then query become "select * from client,client_field where client.name in clientfield.list" list is field of table contain ('jhon','peter')         "

it fixed ,first i make select to get list value ,

"select  clientfield.list from client_field where clientfield.id=1 "
and set result in php variable $listValues ;

then make second statement select * from client where client.name in '". $listValues."' 

the main issue fixed by use utf8_general_ci for datafield collation

Answer (score 1):

you could lower both and compare:

```
SELECT  LOWER('John')  IN  (LOWER('john'),LOWER('Peter'));
```

this will return 1

Comment: but if it come from data field in a table like ('jhon','peter');

then query become 

"select * from client,client_field where client.name in clientfield.list"
list is field of table contain ('jhon','peter')

Comment: that is not a valid sql statement. if you want to compare one field with another field with multiple data, your sql structure should have a seperate table and you should do IN search in that table using subquery.

Comment: thanks, i create a sql statment using php , and isuue fixed by convert collation to utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

with LIKE statment you ignore case sensitive

```
    'John'  LIKE  '%john%' or 'John' LIKE '%Peter%'
```